# Is a sandwich appropriate here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

On an exam we were asked: what is the domain of the following function?

$$\large f(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{x-2}}{\frac{2x+7}{x-1}}$$

My solution:

> This is the same as 
>   $$\large \frac{\frac{x}{x-2}}{1}\times\frac{1}{\frac{2x+7}{x-1}}$$
>   so the domain is $\mathbb R\backslash\{1,2,-\frac72\}$

Teacher's solution:

> Use sandwich law to see it is the same as $\frac{x(x-1)}{(2x+7)(x-2)}$ and therefore the domain is $\mathbb R\backslash\{-\frac72,2\} $

I argue you need to look at the order of operations and see first you must evaluate the two halfs independently, but I can't convince her.

Comment: Wow that's big!

Comment: If you evaluated the expression **as given** at $a$, with a calculator, the calculator would choke on $a=1,2,-7/2$. I think your answer is the more reasonable one.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't it possible to have an infinity if it occurs in the denominator? So x=-1 should be allowed. But are we really on guesses here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct; her answer is for the function without its removable singularity at $x=1$, which has a different domain. That is like arguing the domain of $(x+1)/(x^2-1)$ only excludes $x=-1$ because it can be reduced to $1/(x-1)$ -- while they're identical almost everywhere their domains differ because of the point $x=-1$.